# Angular 1.x - Pass component state resolve data to other component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a dummy component based application, which has the following components:

```
- App
-- Page
---- Breadcrumb
```

What i want is to pass the `Page` resolve data to the `Breadcrumb`.

This is how the `Page` config looks like:

```
$stateProvider.state('page', {
  url: '/page',
  component: 'page',
  resolve: {
    routes: ($stateParams) => {
     "ngInject";

     return [
        {url: "/", name: "Home"},
        {url: "/page", name: 'Page'}
      ];
    }
  }
})
```

The `Page` controller:

```
class PageController {
  constructor($stateParams) {
    "ngInject";


    this.themeColor = "#ff8fd1";

    // When i use static data it's works fine..
    //this.routes = [
    //  {url: "/", name: "Main page"},
    //  {url: "/page", name: 'Sub page'},
    //];

    this.routes = $stateParams.routes;
  }
}
```

And this is my `Breadcrumb` component:

```
let breadcrumbComponent = {
  restrict: 'E',
  bindings: {
    themeColor: "&lt;",
    routes: "&lt;"
  },
  template,
  controller
};
```

The DOM of the `Breadcrumb` component:

```
<breadcrumb theme-color="$ctrl.themeColor" routes="$ctrl.routes"></breadcrumb>
```

Everytime the routes are undefined when i want to define it from the Page controller resolve method.

**How do i wait the data, or bind the `Breadcrumb` again when the data arrives?**

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to use `ngIf` directive to render `breadcrumb` component only when routes are resolved:

```
<breadcrumb 
    ng-if="$ctrl.routes"
    theme-color="$ctrl.themeColor" 
    routes="$ctrl.routes"></breadcrumb>
```

Comment: As much i know the core concept of angular components is there isn't have a two-way bindig. So in this case the ngIf is not the right solution for me... i think i have to redefine the the whole structure of the application, and instead of component maybe i had to use a directive

Comment: As I said, this is simples solution which works well in most cases. Another one could be to use $onChanges hook.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out.

If you're want to pass resolve data to your component, or an other you have to set the resolve data as binding in the parent component as well.

```
// page.component.js

let pageComponent = {
  restrict: 'E',
  bindings: {
    routes: "<"
  },
  template,
  controller
};
```